# How can I specify a logback rolling appender in application.yml?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, logback, slf4j

Is it possible to set a rolling appender in application.yml?

In our project, we are able to externalize our application.yml, but other files are more difficult to externalize.

Therefore we would like to include all of our logging properties in application.yml, rather than in logback.xml.

However I am not seeing a way to specify the rolling policy. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest release of Spring Boot, assuming you're using Spring Boot 2, log files are automatically rolled at `10MB`.

First, specify `logging.file` or `logging.path` in your `application.yaml` to the location of your log file or log path. If you want to change the roll size to something other than `10MB`, change the property `logging.file.max-size`.

By default, previously rotated files are kept indefinitely unless `logging.file.max-history` is set. Set this to the number of rolled files you would like to keep. These only work for the default logback provider included with Spring Boot.

You can see all of the `logging` properties that can be set in `application.yaml` in reference 1 below:

References:

1. [Spring Boot Common Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)
2. [Logging File Output Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output)

Comment: Thanks @devshawn - This is helpful. Is there a comparable way to roll it by date?

Answer (score 1):

```
logging:
file:
  name: log/my-log.log
pattern:
  file: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, Australia/Sydney} %-5level  - %msg%n'
logback:
  rollingpolicy:
    file-name-pattern: 'log/archived/my-log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd, Australia/Sydney}.%i.log'
    max-file-size: 10MB
    max-history: 60
```